# How to read an excel file with empty tabs in R?

Tags: r, excel

I am importing an excel file in R. Some of its tabs are empty. R is not reading those tabs. It gives me an error : Skipped all Data.

```
library(readxl)
sheetnames = excel_sheets("Saudi Diapers.xlsx")
k = length(sheetnames)
i=1

for(i in 1:k) {

  abc = read_excel("Saudi Diapers.xlsx",i`,col_names = T)

  rownames(abc) = NULL

  tabname = paste(sheetnames[i], ".csv")

  write.csv(file=paste("Saudi Diapers",tabname,sep = "_"), x= abc, row.names = F,na="",sep = "")

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to read the empty tabs? Or are you just interested in the ones that are not empty?

Comment: I actually want to read every sheet of the excel in R... I do not know whih tabs are empty or non empty..but I want to read both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:
1. Alter the function `read_excel` in such a way that it doesn't trow an error, but returns an empty dataframe
2. Catch the error with `tryCatch` and return an empty dataframe.
I have chosen for the second option here. The tryCatch function essentially tries to execute a expression (in this case `read_excel(...)`) and if that generates an error, it return the function in the error-condition (in this case `data.frame(NULL)`).

```
library(readxl)
```

I have made a excel sheet with one filled and two empty sheets.
    filename <- "test_blanksheet.xlsx" #Put your own filename here

```
sheetnames = excel_sheets(filename)

for(i in 1:length(sheetnames)) {

  tempdf = tryCatch(read_excel(filename,i,col_names = T), 
                 error = function(err) { data.frame(NULL)})

  write.csv(file=paste0("Saudi_Diapers_",sheetnames[i],".csv"), x= tempdf,
  row.names = F,na="")
      }
```

And it works:

> > list.files()
> >     [1] "Saudi_Diapers_Data2.csv"  "Saudi_Diapers_Empty1.csv"
> >     [3] "Saudi_Diapers_Empty3.csv" "test_blanksheet.xlsx"